read a csv and then read an excel spreadsheet then compare the description in csv and see if it exists as a column heading using python
This is my first program in my project.
I want to read the .csv and compare to an excel spreadsheet.
If it doesn't exist then create it.
If it exists then compare against it.
To create then field 1 is date,2 is amount, 3 is Description.
Then output the values accordingly.
Does this make sense? output excel file is same as input .xls
import csv
# csv file name
filename = "ANZ.csv"

# initializing the titles and rows list
fields = []
rows = []

# reading csv file
with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
    # creating a csv reader object
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)

    # extracting field names through first row
    fields = next(csvreader)

    # extracting each data row one by one
    for row in csvreader:
        rows.append(row)

    # get total number of rows
    print("Total no. of rows: %d" % (csvreader.line_num))

# printing the field names
print('Field names are:' + ', '.join(field for field in fields))

# printing first 5 rows
print('\nFirst 5 rows are:\n')
for row in rows[:5]:
    # parsing each column of a row
    for col in row:
        print("%10s" % col, end=" "),
    print('\n')


I can't see that this is likely to be to do with CSS. Perhaps you meant to tag it csv instead?

So read the .csv and compare to an excel spreadsheet You mean cell for cell compare what is in a CSV to what is in an Excel Sheet? If it doesn't exist then create it If what doesn't exist, a cell value that the CSV has or the Sheet that has the same data as the CSV? If it exists then compare against it. is this the dame as the first requirement? ... not sure about the other requirements either. Also are you actually working with XLS or do you mean XLSX files? I didn't change the tag but I agree with @A Haworth that you presumably meant to use csv tag not css?

Are you seriously wanting to parse an xls or xlsx file? Would it be easier to convert that to csv then compare the two csvs?

csv not css. I want to add the value in the next corresponding line that is the same in the description so as to get an excel spreadsheet summing all the values that correspond to the description. its a tax summary using the downloaded transaction (csv) list into a .xlsx or.xls (what works best)
